# How to travel through tubes?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, physics, engineering, transportation

We are in new new York, year 3000-ish. The city is quite big but there is a new transport system.

Tubes, they are everywhere. They suck you in and out: you fly in them, basically.
Those tubes can be kilometer long, go in the ground or in the sky. They can transport human, dog, cat, aliens races, anything up to a 2m diameter.

- Is such a system would physically and engineering possible?
- What is the best material to make it? Should be plastic, metal or glass ?
- Should they be pressurize ?
- Would a system sucking like that cause body damage because of the pressure difference ?
- How does the routing work, it just air, should the user have a GPS ?

Comment: Are you referring to the tube transport form Matt Groening's Futurama?

Comment: Hints: (1) [pneumatic tube transport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pneumatic_tube) systems were used for distribution of correspondence in many major cities from the middle of the 19th century to the middle of the 20th; in 1934 Paris had 467 km of pneumatic post tubes. (2) Elon Musk's [Hyperloop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperloop) is a proposed *" sealed tube or system of tubes through which a pod may travel free of air resistance or friction conveying people or objects at high speed"* (Wikipedia).

Comment: @BladeWraith, the idea predates Futurama by 100 years at least, Groening was just making reference to it as a [future travel trope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pneumatic_tube#In_fiction)

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help]. Have fun!

Comment: @Separatrix, i'm awareit was an old idea, but the fact that the OP asked about New New York in the year 3000-ish...

Comment: Please limit the scope of your question. As it is you are asking five questions in one.

Comment: @BladeWraith yes, definitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with real-world pneumatic tubes is that they work with air pressure differences. They require capsules which have about the same diameter as the tube.

Another propulsion option would be electromagnetic, but that would also require capsules.

If you want to do it without capsules, then the only option I could think of would be artificial gravity. People don't get sucked through the tubes, they fall through the tubes, accelerated by an artificial gravity field. Repelling gravity fields around the walls prevent them from colliding with them, and another repelling gravity field decelerates them at their destination.

There are just two problems with artificial gravity.

1. While physicists know very well how gravity fields affect matter, they do not have any idea how we could create them artificially without just collecting a large amount of mass. So if you want such a technology in your universe, you need to hand-wave the science behind it.
2. If you want to create a hard science fiction universe, keep in mind that artificial gravity technology can have quite amazing implications. When it is so readily available and controlable that you can use it for public transportation, then it can also be used for lots of other purposes. Most SciFi universes ignore this, though. They introduce artificial gravity just because they don't want people to float around in space stations and space ships but don't want rotating sections either. And then they forget about all the other useful things you can do when you can control gravity.

If you don't feel comfortable with the amount of hand-waving required to make artificial gravity work in a science-based universe, then your only option is to use capsules.

> What is the best material to make it? Should be plastic, metal or glass?

1000 years ago you would have asked whether to make it from loam, wood or hewn stones. 200 years ago you would have asked about whether to use concrete, brickwork or wrought iron. In 200 years I would have said "some carbon nanotech stuff". In 1000 years, it is impossible to tell what we will come up with. So you can focus purely on the aesthetic aspects. As long as you don't end up requiring a material with properties which are *completely* implausible, you can safely assume that an appropriate material will be invented within the next 1000 years.

> How does the routing work, it just air, should the user have a GPS ?

There is an app for that :). The user just tells the system where they want to go and it routes them automatically. The junctions should be smart enough to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is 1800-ish, not 3000-ish. It is called [pneumatic tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pneumatic_tube).

> Pneumatic tubes (or capsule pipelines; also known as pneumatic tube transport or PTT) are systems that propel cylindrical containers through networks of tubes by compressed air or by partial vacuum. They are used for transporting solid objects, as opposed to conventional pipelines, which transport fluids. Pneumatic tube networks gained acceptance in the late 19th and early 20th centuries for offices that needed to transport small, urgent packages (such as mail, paperwork, or money) over relatively short distances (within a building, or at most, within a city). Some installations grew to great complexity, but were mostly superseded. In some settings, such as hospitals, they remain widespread and have been further extended and developed in the 21st century.

Technical characteristics:

> Modern systems (for smaller, i.e. “normal”, tube diameters as used in the transport of small capsules) reach speeds of around 7.5 m (25 ft) per second, though some historical systems already achieved speeds of 10 m (33 ft) per second. At the same time, varying air pressures allow capsules to brake slowly, removing the jarring arrival that used to characterise earlier systems and make them unsuitable for fragile contents.
>
> Very powerful systems can transport items with a weight of up to 50 kg (110 lb) and a diameter of up to 500 mm (20 in). More than 100 lines and 1000 stations can be connected.
>
> Further, modern systems can be computer-controlled for tracking of any specific capsule and managing priority deliveries as well as system efficiency. With this technology, time-critical items can be transported, such as tissue samples taken during a surgery in a hospital. RFID-Chips within in the capsules gather data – e. g. about the location of the carrier, its transport speed or its destination. The systems collect and save these data to help users optimize their internal processes and turnaround times. The facilities can be linked to the company’s software systems, e.g. laboratory information systems, for full integration into company logistical management and production chains.

Comment: If you are investing 1 point of reputation into downvoting, you could also put some effort in explaining why.